# entity framework data model and connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I have 2 C# .net applications such as
1. A data access applicatin which has an entity frame work data model to connect to the DB.
2. A web application which will contain the dll of 1st application and getting data by calling functions from dll

I need to take the connection string from the 2nd application web config file and pass it to the 1st application. In the 1st application data should be retrieved according to the connection string from the 2nd application.

Comment: For the 2nd application (web appln) in web.config file the connection string is given as :   <add name="testConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=DataSourse;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=False;user=uname;pwd=passwd;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: But in 1st application (entity frame work data model application) in app.config file the connection string is given as :   <add name="testEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestEntity.csdl|res://*/TestEntity.ssdl|res://*/TestEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source="datasource";initial catalog=testDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Both are in a different syntax i think...   When I tried to do like this   string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(connectionString);  in my 2nd application to connect to the DB, an error (Argument Exception  :  'Keyword not supported: 'data source'') occured.

Comment: How can I manage this..?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways you can achieve this. One (which I won't go into here) is through some kind of bootstrap loader - where you pass a connection string via the constructor of your repository (or data context), or you could construct a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` ([some further details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbowen/archive/2007/03/05/sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)).

If you want to keep things simple, store the connection string in your `web.config` file of your web application, set the key to the name of your object. So let's say you have extended `DbContext` with an object called `MyDbContext`. In the web.config you'll have the following as your connection string

```
<add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="<conn string>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Entity framework will use this connection string automatically, as the key is the same as your context.

Comment: I tried this and got error like  :    'The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.'

Comment: @Sudha can you post the code for your `DbContext` class and the connection string from the web.config file?

Comment: The connection string in the web application's web.config file is like                         <add name="testEntities"
            connectionString="Data Source=datasourse;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=False;user=uname;pwd=password;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: And the code in the edmx file's designer.cs file is something like public partial class testEntities : ObjectContext{public testEntities() : base("name=testEntities", "testEntities"){    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;OnContextCreated();}  public testEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "testEntities"){this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;OnContextCreated();} public testEntities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "testEntities"){this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;     OnContextCreated();}}

Answer (score 0):

If the dll is to act as a data access layer, it should be retrieving the data and passing it to the web application. Not the other way around.

If you choose to do it that way anyway, you'll have to make a function that retrieves the connection string from the app.config of the dll and pass it to the web app.

To access the connection string(s) in the config file of an assembly, us the ConfigurationManager class, (opposed to the WebConfigurationManager class that you would use in a web application). It accesses the elements of the config in the same maner with teh same calls, just intended for generalized config reads/writes.

EDIT: As mentioned by @PaulAldred-Bann, the connection string "should" be stored in the web apps config file if it is needed in the web app as well. The assembly would still have access to this (you would just move the settings to the web.config from the app.config. The reason it can be accessed from there is, the assembly, when referenced, acts on behalf of the caller (in this case, the web app).

Comment: The problem with VS 2013 and EF6 is that the calling application must pass the connection string.  This is poor encapsulation.  In most cases, the web application should not need to know about the database connectivity (if the dll is handling the access).  However, MS requires this for some reason.  This must be an unintended side effect.